# How to update a custom field when user is logged out of salesforce without showing any screen?

Tags: visual-workflow, loginflow, flow-builder

I want to reset a "counter__c" custom field on user/contact object(community license user) whenever user session ends (or restarts). How can I catch log out or log in event for that user and clear this field value?

Note that this is a community user. (Customer Commnuity Plus user license)

I tried using Log in flows in combination of "Screen" flow from flow builder, but it did not update the custom field.

Flow:

[image]

In resetCounter assignment, I am assgining counter__c = 0;

[image]

where {!userCounter} is a new variable that I created that has default value = User.counter__c (ignore error, removed namespace here)

[image]

Comment: Logout: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_auth_create_logout_event_trigger.htm&type=5

Comment: This trigger does not fire when log out is due to time out, unless force logout is selected. Don't want the dependency on this setting